# Wordpress SQL query to fetch the meta_key names in a custom post type

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

Using WP dataTables plugin and my MySQL sucks so please bear with me.

I'm trying to fetch multiple associated meta_keys (custom field names) that are allocated to a custom post type in WordPress, and display the fields as the table header with the custom field values in the rows underneath the header.

My SQL below kinda works. While it pulls in a colum called 'meta_key' and 'meta_value', it has the actual names of the key as it's data.  I want the meta_key value itself as the list returned.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'call_date' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'call_time' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'caller_number' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'call_duration' OR wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'call_status' ) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT
```

So this creates a table with the header as 'meta_key' but I want the custom field name itself as the header.  Hope this makes sense.

PS I've also tried

```
SELECT caller_number, call_duration, call_status, call_date, call_time
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type =  'my_custom_post'
AND post_status =  'publish'
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id = post_id
```

But it shows no data...

Seriously, any help here would be awesome.

Comment: In my Wordpress meta table each key has a space before the actual key. Not sure why it's like this.

Answer (score 0):

for specific keys

```
get_post_meta($postid, '_metakey', single);
```

for all keys

```
get_post_meta($postid);
```

so you can do a foreach loop if you return just the custom posts in your sql query. But for posts, wp_query does a good job of returning posts rather than custom mysql queried.

Comment: Hi, this isn't needed via PHP (I can do that), this is for purely a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

See what is all returning...

```
global $wpdb;
global $post;

$cpt = "my_custom_post";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta 
ON {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.post_id 
WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = '$cpt' 
AND ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish' OR {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ({$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = 'call_date' OR {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = 'call_time' OR {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = 'caller_number' OR {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = 'call_duration' OR {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.meta_key = 'call_status' ) 
ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}posts.menu_order, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC";

$data = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";

die();
```